# Can `&&` inside a higher order function parameter be a forwarding reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

The canonical example of a [forwarding](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (or universal reference) goes like so:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param);
```

i.e.

> "If a variable or parameter is declared to have type T&& for some deduced type T, that variable or parameter is a universal reference."

But consider a more contrived example:

```cpp
 #include <iostream>

 class MyClass
 {
     int _val;

   public:
     void set_val(int &&newVal)
     {
         _val = newVal;
         std::cout << "New val = " << _val << std::endl;
     }
 };

 template <class T, class V> void evoke(void (T::*method)(V &&))
 // The && appears inside the context of a function type  ^^^^ argument
 {
     T obj;
     (obj.*method)(2);
 }

 int main()
 {
     evoke(&MyClass::set_val);
 }
```

In such cases I find it puzzling to follow the aforementioned rule. `V` is certainly deduced, but not on its own. Even though it's not a forwarding reference in the example above, can such constructs (function or member function pointer parameters) produce a forwarding reference for **their** arguments? Does the rule still apply in such cases?

Comment: AFAIK only `TemplateParameter &&`  produces a forwarding reference.  Everything else is just an rvalue reference.

Comment: interesting question. I posted the obvious answer, but I am only 99% sure about it ;)

Comment: Reference collapsing happens for template type parameters (`V` is such) no matter where in the signature they appear.  `V&&` is reference-collapsed in `evoke<T, V>`.   `MyClass::set_val` can obviously not have any forwarding reference, because it isn't a function template

Comment: Is your actual question whether `V` deduces to `int` or `int&&` for the call `evoke(&MyClass::set_val)`?

Comment: @BenVoigt The question is whether `V` is a forwarding reference. To the best of my it's not and doesn't behave as such when the signature of `set_val` is changed to `void set_val(int &newVal)` (i.e. there's a compilation error). So I'd argue against your point about reference collapsing above. But again, I can't pin point the standard quote to support my findings

Comment: @BenVoigt By "forwarding reference" I mean the type is such that `evoke` can be instantiated for member functions `void fun(int& val)`  AND `void fun2(int&& val)`

Comment: @LorahAttkins: But see, that's not what *forwarding reference* means in the standard.  Yes, `evoke()` can be called with both `void MyClass::fun(int& lvr)` and `void MyClass::fun2(int&& rvr)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) (emphasize mine):

> Forwarding references are a special kind of references that preserve the value category of a function argument, making it possible to forward it by means of `std::forward`. Forwarding references are either:
>
> 1. function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue reference to cv-unqualified type template parameter **of that same function template**:
>
> [... examples ...]
>
> 2. `auto&&` except when deduced from a brace-enclosed initializer list:
>
> [... more examples ...]

For what its worth, the relevant section in the standard is [`[temp.deduct.call]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#3). My standardese is not fluent, but to my understanding the description on cppreference (must be parameter of a function template) is accurate.